# java sending hashmap to Freemarker template not working correct, undefined parameter

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

```
Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
model.put("A", "1");
model.put("b", "2");
model.put("c", "3");
try{
 content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(configuration.getTemplate(ftlName), model));
...
```

and Ftl file looks like this :

```
<html><head></head><body>
${model["A"]}

<#list model?keys as prop>
    ${model[prop]}
</#list>
</body>
</html>
```

Hwoever I am getting the error :

```
Expression model is undefined on line 6, column 3 in vslEmail.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${model["A"]} [on line 6, column 1 in vslEmail.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression model is undefined on line 6, column 3 in vslEmail.ftl.
```

I get the same error if I remove try to access `model` using only the list directive ... any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is stupidly perplexed like I was you have to do this in FTL :

```
<html><head></head><body>
${A}
</body>
</html>
```

or make A a hashmap instead of a string and loop through that, not the "top" model object.